# How to get module name from a given route object?

Tags: routes

In a runtime context, given I have a route object, e.g. from route name `user.register`, how do I find the path or routing.yml or other definer of the route?

Does Drupal or Symfony provide for this?

There's probably a better way to do what I want. The scenario I have is: a plugin manager is deciding which plugin to instantiate based on route context. For example, if module `foo` defines route `foo.bar` at path `/foo/bar`, the plugin manager will instantiate plugin `foo_plugin`. If module, `zee` defines route `zee.bang` at path `/zee/bang`, the plugin manager will instantiate `zee_plugin`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? This doesn't seem the real question for which you need an answer, as which module implements a route is normally not useful to write code for a module/theme.

Comment: You're right, there's probably a better way to do what I want. The scenario I have is: a plugin manager is deciding which plugin to instantiate based on route context. For example, if module `foo` defines route `foo.bar` at path `/foo/bar`, the plugin manager will instantiate plugin `foo_plugin`. If module, `zee` defines route `zee.bang` at path `/zee/bang`, the plugin manager will instantiate `zee_plugin`

Comment: Edit the question to add what you just said. Don't forget to add an explicit, not broad, question too. Remember that _best way_ is seen as subjective.

Comment: The route object itself has no reference to the route name. This is for example why they needed to add a route name to OutboundRouteProcessor, see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2346283